# How to understand "Changes in" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

I saw a weird sentence in [a dictionary website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) where I'm studying.

This is the sentence what I'm getting confused;

> ***Changes in*** atmospheric pressure are producing these strange weather conditions.
>
> > (Rephrase) Atmospheric pressure causes these strange weather conditions.
> >
> > (Rephrase) These strange weather conditions are involved in atmospheric pressure.

I've seen someone using "changing in" in front of the sentence, but never saw ***changes in***. What's the ***changes in*** stand for in the above sentence?

Can I say "changing in" instead of ***changes in***? Whether or not, what's the difference between those 2 words?

Comment: You *definitely* can't replace plural noun ***changes*** with (continuous participle? gerund?) ***changing*** in your context. But you *can* replace the "simple" noun with a verb-derived gerund noun in some similar contexts: ***Work** here is well-paid* and ***Working** here is well-paid* are both valid, and effectively mean the same thing. Is that the kind of example that made you think you could use ***changing***? If we knew *why* you thought ***changing*** might be an acceptable alternative, it might be easier for someone to explain exactly why you were mistaken.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ;Do you wonder if you can use changing?' Yes, and at first, I was misreading the plural noun `changes` as a `verb` and then I thought there was an omitted word `it` in front of the sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But without that, I still wonder how to understand the plural noun `changes` in that sentence.

Comment: The cited assertion strikes me as a bit vacuous at the level of meaning, but *syntactically* it might be easier to deconstruct it with ***temperature*** instead of ***atmospheric pressure*** - "**Changes in temperature** are causing unusual weather". Which is syntactically much the same as "**Increases in prices** are causing hardship in my town". Note that both those assertions are a bit klunky. We're much more likely to say "**Temperature changes** are causing unusual weather" and "**Price increases** are causing hardship in my town".

Comment: I might have just realised what's confusing you. The preposition ***in*** (or ***to***, which is a valid alternative here with almost exactly the same meaning) is only required when connecting nouns "changes" and "temperature". Alternative phrasing with a "verb-based" initial term doesn't need a preposition: "**Changing temperatures** are causing unusual weather". Note that idiomatically it it would be fine to have singular "**Changing temperature is** causing unusual weather". Note that singular "**Temperature change is** causing unusual weather" is also syntactically fine.

Comment: It isn't the atmospheric pressure that is causing the strange conditions, but the fact that the pressure is changing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry for the delayed response, and I appreciate your detailed explanation even though my question is out of topic and unclear. I was trying to ask the rules of plural noun form (changes in, which I misread to plural verb at the first time.) because these 2 words, ***change*** and ***changing*** both have their own noun forms. I was wondering the differentiate between those word denotative or connotative meanings. But I think you’ve already answered from your previous comments.